# Jars needed for exporting ireport to pdf in netbeans

Tags: java, pdf, jar, ireport, netbeans7.0

I have a little issue, I've designed a report using iReport 4.1.1 plugin for Netbeans IDE 7.0.
I want to export to pdf, so I imported the following:
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*;
    import java.util.*;
But I get the error:
    package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
    package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export does not exist
I guess the problem is simply because I do not know the jar file to add, where to locate them nor the directory to put them.
I will appreciate anyone who can give me a detailed correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you search for jar dependencies, as well as to read the documentation on the productor of the library (in this case Jasperforge), you can serach for dependencies defined in Maven repositories; you can do this even if you don't use Maven for your builds.

Maven POMs are quite understandable XML files and sites that host Maven repositories often have front ends to allow an easy reading of a POM.

If you go for example to [Maven repository for JasperReports 3.5.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jasperreports/jasperreports/3.5.3), you can see all dependencies and make yourself an idea to what jars you have to search for and download for your issue.